# Remove coma separated string from another coma separated string in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
Column1 =A,B,C,D,E,F
Column2  =C,D,A,F,C,B (It can have duplicates)
```

I need to remove column2 values from column1 and get the missing value.

Desired output

```
(Column1)-(Column2) = E
```

Comment: I tried it and it is taking time to execute. Performance is bit slow with this approach

Comment: If you're commenting code I posted as an answer, then it is FAST, given it works only on two columns in a table with a single row. If environment you work on is different (e.g. a table with many rows), you should have said so and posted more information.

Comment: You do know that this is not how to use a relational database? We strive for normalized tables. One of the very basic criteria is that data is atomic (one value per column). Comma-separated data is only then okay, when you want to remain oblivious to the content in the database (so from the point of the database this data is considered atomic). You however, want to deal with the single elements in the csv strings. Use child tables to establish 1:n relations instead.

Answer (score 2):

Split columns' contents into rows, use `MINUS` set operator. Sample data in lines #1 - 3; query begins at line #4.

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'C,D,A,F,C,B' from dual
  3    )
  4  select regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  5    from test
  6    connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1
  7  minus
  8  select regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  9    from test
 10    connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ',') + 1
 11  /

VAL
--------------------------------------------
E

SQL>
```

---

If you're comparing columns in a multi-row table, the above approach won't work OK as it'll retrieve duplicates and will be slow. In that case, rewrite it to

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'C,D,A,F,C,B' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'A,B,B,B' from dual
  4    )
  5  select id, listagg(val, ',') within group (order by val) missing_letters
  6  from
  7  (
  8  select id,
  9         regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) val
 10    from test cross join
 11      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                          connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1
 13                         ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  minus
 15  select id,
 16         regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) val
 17    from test cross join
 18      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 19                          connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ',') + 1
 20                         ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 21  )
 22  group by id;

        ID MISSING_LETTERS
---------- --------------------
         1 E
         2 C,D,E,F

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`translate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) function with additional cleanup logic to remove all remaining commas. This will work only for single character replacement (one character between commas), but doesn't require to split string into tokens and uses simple string functions.

> ```
> with a(col1, col2) as (
>   select 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'C,D,A,F,C,B' from dual
> )
> select
>   /*Then remove leading and trailing commas*/
>   trim(',' from
>     /*Then condense all intermediate commas and spaces*/
>     regexp_replace(
>       /*Do actual replacement*/
>       translate(col1, replace(col2, ','), ' '),
>       '[, ]+', ','
>     )
>   ) as res
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | RES |
> | :-- |
> | E   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da9aa7fce80dc199d6f14b99babc32c2)*

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to split the string.

If your delimited values do not have any characters with special meaning in regular expressions then you can double-up the delimiters in `col1` and then convert `col2` to a regular expression and replace matches with an empty string and then remove the excess delimiters:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       TRIM(
         BOTH ',' FROM
         REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ',' || REPLACE(col1, ',', ',,') || ',',
             ',(' || REPLACE(col2, ',', '|') || '),'
           ),
           ',,',
           ','
         )
       ) AS missing
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'C,D,A,F,C,B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,AB,BA,B,',  'A,B'         FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 | MISSING |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A,B,C,D,E,F | C,D,A,F,C,B | E |
> | A,AB,BA,B, | A,B | AB,BA |

---

If you do have characters with special meaning then you can do a similar replacement using a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH replacements ( col1, col2 ) AS (
  SELECT ',' || REPLACE( col1, ',', ',,') || ',',
         col2 || ','
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT REPLACE(col1, ',' || SUBSTR(col2, 1, INSTR(col2, ','))),
         SUBSTR(col2, INSTR(col2, ',') + 1)
  FROM   replacements
  WHERE  col2 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(col1, ',,', ',')) AS missing
FROM   replacements
WHERE  col2 IS NULL
```

Which outputs:

> | MISSING |
> | --- |
> | AB,BA |
> | E |

*Note: both of these queries only require a single table scan.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5ac38ce15d679bc60b42a26f4ce74fe6)*

Answer (score 2):

Using `ora:tokenize` you could do something like this (including a few test cases in the `with` clause; you should remove it, and use your actual table and column names in the main query):

```
with
  inputs (col1, col2) as (
    select 'A,B,C,D,E,F', 'C,D,A,F,C,B' from dual union all
    select 'D,,F'       , 'F,A'         from dual union all
    select 'A,B,E,F'    , 'E'           from dual union all
    select 'ABC'        , 'A,B,ABC'       from dual
  )
--  END OF TEST DATA; QUERY BEGINS **BELOW THIS LINE**
select i.col1, i.col2, l.diff
from   inputs i cross join lateral
       ( select listagg(token, ',') within group (order by null) as diff
         from   xmltable('ora:tokenize(.,",")' passing i.col1 || ',' 
                         columns token varchar2(10) path '.')
         where  not ',' || col2 || ',' like '%,' || token || ',%'       ) l
;

COL1        COL2        DIFF                
----------- ----------- --------------------
A,B,C,D,E,F C,D,A,F,C,B E                   
D,,F        F,A         D                   
A,B,E,F     E           A,B,F               
ABC         A,B,ABC
```